# Facing problem for CustomRouteHandler with 301 parmanent redirection in asp.net webform project

Tags: asp.net, routes

i manage to develop a custom route handler for asp.net routing. i develop to deal with 301 parmanent redirection. here is my full code

```
public class CustomRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public CustomRouteHandler(string virtualPath)
    {
        VirtualPath = virtualPath;
    }

    public string VirtualPath { get; private set; }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {

        if (requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.LocalPath.Contains("?"))
        { }

        requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        requestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 301;
        requestContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Location", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.LocalPath);


        var page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath
                       (VirtualPath, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page)) as IHttpHandler;

        return page;
    }

}

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        RouteTable.Routes.Add("Source", new Route
        (
           "UrlRewrite/Approach1/Source/{ID}/{Title}",
           new CustomRouteHandler("~/UrlRewrite/Approach1/Source.aspx")
        ));

    }
```

actually the below lines giving me the problem
            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 301;
            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Location", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.LocalPath);

for the above line the same page is requested again & again just like infinite loop.
so please guide me what to do.....thanks

Comment: did you solve this issue? I am also getting the same error for my handler